# How to link an annotation for a hibernate validation in my Class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I would like to create an annotation that takes a min value = 0, for attemptCount property in my Class. I created a:

```
package com.ctp.interactive.bl.core.validation.validator;

import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;

@Min(value = ValidAttemptCount.MIN_VALUE)
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(java.lang.annotation.ElementType.FIELD)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {})
public @interface ValidAttemptCount {

    int MIN_VALUE = 0;

    String message() default "";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

But I think that it doesn't work only by put the annotation above the property eg:

```
@ValidAttemptCount
@Column(name = "attempt_count")
private Integer attemptCount;
```

What is the missing step here?

Comment: Why not just place `@Min(0)` on the `attemptCount` field?

Comment: I think that if you put only the annotation it is working as Documentation and not as a Constraint.

Comment: The standard `@Min` annotation **is** a constraint annotation and will be handled appropriately by a `Validator`. You can see in [the documentation](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/validation/constraints/Min.html) it's annotated with `@Constraint(validatedBy = {})`. Note the array is empty because it's a built-in constraint annotation and thus handled specially.

Comment: If you're looking to create a custom constraint, see https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-customconstraints. If you're looking to use constraint composition, see https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-constraint-composition

Comment: @Slaw @Min(value=0) worked fine! Thanks for your help!